# Proxy issue while running script

Tags: selenium, webdriver, watir-webdriver, selenium-grid2

I'm trying to use Selenium Grid2 to run concurrent Watir WebDriver scripts.  I have the started the hub successfully, as I can open it up in my browser and I've spawned two nodes, each of which show in the console.

I started the node by doing this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=WatirWebDriver
```

I then attempted to run a test script:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.ie
caps.platform = :WINDOWS
caps[:name] = "WatirWebDriver"

browser = Watir::Browser.new(
  :remote,
  :url => "http://xxxxxxxx:5555",
  :desired_capabilities => caps)

browser.goto "http://www.google.com"
```

*where xxxx is local IP"

This returns a 403 Proxy error.

I can run this script basic script locally just fine in which I've just created a new IE browser instance and then told it to go to google. However, I did try setting http_proxy with my company's proxy information and that didn't work either.  That however gave me an access denied error when I ran the script both locally and through the node.  However, I know the creds are correct.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I needed to be pointing to /wd/hub foor the url: http://xxxxxxxx:5555/wd/hub

Once I did that, it worked.  Should have done more research before posting question...